# Raspberry Pi Zero W + Adafruit Thermal Printer Only printing limited number of characters

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-jessie, serial, pi-zero-w, printing

I'm trying to set up an [Adafruit Thermal printer Mode: CSN-A2-T](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/CSN-A2+User+Manual.pdf) with a [Raspberry Pi Zero W](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-zero-w/) that is running Raspbian GNU/Linux 9.4 (which I believe is Raspbian Jessie).

I need to be able to print using either the terminal or Python (or any other programming language) but the problem is that the printer is only printing a limited quantity of characters.

If I send for instance "0123456789abcdef" (sometimes less, sometimes more) it works, but if I try to print "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrst..." or any other long text It stops working or it starts printing random characters.

The printer's test page prints just fine and this issue doesn't appear.

This is the tutorial I used to set it up: https://learn.adafruit.com/networked-thermal-printer-using-cups-and-raspberry-pi/connect-and-configure-printer

These are the commands I'm using to print:

Using LPR:

```
echo "This is a test." | lpr
```

Sendind a text to the serial port directly:

```
echo -e "This is a test.\\n\\n\\n" > /dev/serial0
```

This is the printed test page holding the feed button (my printer have one) while connecting power as the tutorial said:
[image: test page]

This is how it prints a short text:
[image: short test]

This is how it prints a large test (notice that before it was printing correctly): 
[image: long test]

Finally this is the printer setup:
[image: settings]
[image: job options]

I hope there's enough information. Thanks for your help :) .